# 30 v 20 sided die i thought were same question

Tags: probability, dice

I ran across this question:

> Alice and Bob have fair 30-sided and 20-sided dice, respectively. The
> goal is to obtain the largest possible value. Alice rolls her die one
> time. However, Bob can roll his die twice and keep the maximum of the
> two values. In the event of a tie, Bob is the winner. Find the
> probability Alice is the winner.

The answer to this is $\frac{647}{1200}$, you basically use LOTP and find the pmf.

Then I ran into this question:

> Alice and Bob have fair 30-sided and 20-sided dice, respectively. The
> goal for each player is to have the largest value on their die. Alice
> and Bob both roll their dice. However, Bob has the option to re-roll
> his die in the event that he is unhappy with the outcome. He can see
> Alice's die beforehand. Bob then keeps the value of the new die roll.
> In the event of a tie, Bob is the winner. Assuming optimal play by
> Bob, find the probability Alice is the winner.

The answer to this is $\frac{17}{30}$.

Why are these not the exact same question? Both just check to see if the max of Bob exceeds Alice, right? In the second one, it isn't phrased like that specifically, but I feel like it should be the same.

**EDIT: HERE IS THE PROOF FOR $\frac{17}{30}$. To be honest, I don't understand the second half of it [EDIT 2: Seems like the provided answer does not answer the question first asked.**

Let $W$ be the event Alice wins. First, we want to find $P(W)$. Let $A$ and $B$ be value of Alice's roll and Bob's first roll, respectively. The key here is to condition on whether or not $A < 20$. Namely, this means $P(W)= P(W| A \leq 20) P (A \leq 20) + P(W | A > 20) P (A > 20)$.

We can quickly see that $P(A \leq 20) = \frac{2}{3}$, as this accounts for 20 of 30 equally-likely values. If $A > 20$, then clearly Alice wins regardless of what Bob obtains, so $P(W | A > 20) = 1$.

If $A < 20$, then we are really rolling 2 independent 20-sided fair dice. Namely, to compute $P(W | A < 20)$, we see that the probability of a tie is $\frac{1}{20}$, as there are 20 values the can agree upon out of $20^2 = 400$ outcomes. Therefore, the probability the two rolls are different is $\frac{19}{20}$.Because of the fact that the two dice are symmetric, $P(A > B) = \frac{19}{20}\frac{1}{2} = \frac{19}{40}$ as when the two rolls are not the same, it is equally-likely whether $A > B$ or $A < B$.

Combining these all together, we see that $P(W) = \frac{1}{3} 1 + \frac{2}{3}\frac{19}{40}$. Now, Bob is going to roll again whenever $P(W | B = b) = 1- \frac{b}{30} > \frac{39}{60}$. This is because he wants to minimize Alice's chances of winning. It is easy to see that $P(W | B = b) = 1 - \frac{b}{30}$, as Aice just needs to roll a value of at least $b + 1$.

We just need to find the maximum value of $b$, say $b^*$ such that $P(W | B = b) = 1 - \frac{b}{30} > \frac{39}{60}$. Solving this inequality, we get that $b \leq 10.5$, so $b^* = 10$ is the maximum value that Bob rolls again. Let $W_1$ be the event that Alice wins in this new game where Bob can roll again. We have that

$P(W_1) = P(W) + \frac{10}{20}(P(W) - P(W | B \leq 10))$.

We get this because of the fact that Bob rolls again with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, which is when he rolls at most 10. Then, the probability Alice wins is going to
change by $P(W) - P(W | B \leq 10)$.

To calculate $P(W | B < 10)$, this is simply just average all the cases where $B = b$ for $1 \leq b \leq 10$, as when $B \leq 10$, the value is uniformly distributed on the first 10 positive integers. Therefore,

$P(W | B < 10) = \frac{1}{10}\sum_{b = 1}^10 1 - \frac{b}{30} = \frac{49}{60}$

Therefore, we get that

$P(W) = \frac{39}{60} + \frac{1}{2}(\frac{39}{60} - \frac{49}{60}) = \frac{17}{30}$

Comment: "Why are these not the exact same question?" -- In the second one, Bob doesn't have to roll twice, and a maximum is not taken.

Comment: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4771790/probability-of-winning-in-a-20-30-split-die-game) was asked earlier.  I agree with you, I see the two problems as identical.  In both, $B$ wins if and only if his max (of two) is at least as big as $A's$.  Mind you, that OP also reported that others were getting a different answer so...perhaps they aren't equivalent?  I'll think about that a bit.

Comment: I can't see any meaningful difference.  I've posted a proof of equivalence below...if I am missing something, perhaps that will make it easier for someone to spot.

Comment: Perhaps you could link to an argument that gives $\frac {17}{30}$ as an answer?

Comment: @lulu I added the solution posted; I don't really understand it though

Comment: @nezamjazayeri  In that calculation, it appears that Bob *does not* know what Alice threw.  As has been stated, that is a critical assumption.  If Bob doesn't see Alice's toss, then Bob might throw away a winner in search of a better roll.

Comment: I hope I didn't mistype anything

Comment: @lulu this is what I was thinking too, that's why I didn't understand the solution. I'd assume wherever the question was posted mistyped the question

Comment: @nezamjazayeri  It says that Bob will re-roll on a $10$.  That makes complete sense if he doesn't know what $A$ threw.  After all, he expects to get $10.5$ so he should go for it.  But, obviously, if he knows what $A$ threw then there's no optionality for him...he re-rolls if he's got a loser and not if he has a winner.

Comment: @lulu yep, I know. I just meant their proof didn't make any sense in answering the original question. Somehow the question still doesn't make sense though -- it is implying Bob sees the roll if he wins on his first roll and doesn't see the roll if he doesn't win

Comment: As I say, they are analyzing a different game.  Perfectly sensible game!  But different.  Since Bob is flying blind, he could certainly discard a winner.  That gives Alice an advantage.

Comment: Note:  I have edited my post to include the computation for the version of the problem in which Bob *does not* see Alice's toss but still has the option to re-roll.

Answer (score 1):

Proof of equivalence I:

Of course, in the "max" version, Bob wins iff the max is at least as great as Alice's roll.

Now, consider the "option" version, and let Bob's rolls be $b_1,b_2$, and Alice's be $a$.  Of course, if $b_1≥a$, Bob wins.  But in that case, $\max(b_1, b_2)≥b_1≥a$ so the max wins.  If $b_1<a$, Bob will take $b_2$ instead and then wins iff $b_2≥a$.  But in that case $\max(b_1, b_2)=b_2≥a$.  Thus, Bob's win is the same as saying that $\max(b_1, b_2)≥a$.

Proof II (rephrasing I):    Bob wins iff at least one of $b_1,b_2$ is $≥a$.  That's the same as requiring that $\max(b_1, b_2)≥a$.

Unless I am missing something, the two versions of the game are equivalent.  Of course, it is very different if, in the option version, Bob doesn't see Alice's toss.  In that case, if Bob's $b_1=6$ or whatever, he might feel obliged to go with the second roll.  That could cost him the game, in the scenario where $b_1≥a$ but $b_2<a$.  Of course, if Bob sees that $b_1≥a$, the game is over.

For completeness, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1-Sum%5B%28%28i%2F20%29%5E2-%28%28i-1%29%2F20%29%5E2%29*i%2F30%2C%7Bi%2C1%2C20%7D%5D) is the calculation for the "max" version, yielding $\frac {647}{1200}$ as expected.

Post edit:  it appears that the confusion does indeed concern the rule regarding what Bob knows.  If Bob sees Alice's toss, then the games are equivalent.  If Bob does not see Alice's toss, then that gives Alice a clear advantage (since Bob might well discard a winner).  For that problem we consider the probability that Bob ends up with a particular value (assuming that Bob plays optimally and re-rolls if he gets $≤10$ on the first try).  For that one $p_i=\frac 12\times \frac 1{20}$ if $i≤10$ since the only way to get such a bad roll is to discard the first (probability $\frac 12$) and then roll $i$ (probability $\frac 1{20}$).  If $i>10$ then $p_i=\frac 1{20}+\frac 12\times \frac 1{20}$ since Bob might get $i$ initially or on the reroll.  Thus the probability that Bob wins this version is $$\sum_{i=1}^{20}p_i\times \frac i{30}=\frac {13}{30}$$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the computation of the probability of Alice's winning is $~\dfrac{17}{30}.~$

This implies that the probability of Bob winning is

$$\frac{13}{30}. \tag1 $$

The computation in (1) above does not apply to the posted game.  However, it does apply to the following **altered** version of the game:

- Assume that Bob must decide whether to re-roll without any knowledge of Alice's roll.
- Also assume that if Bob re-rolls, he is forced to keep his second roll, regardless of whether the first roll was higher.

Assuming that Bob plays optimally, what is the probability of Bob winning?

---

To answer this question, you must first answer a preliminary question.  Assuming that Bob and Alice each roll **only once**, what is the probability of Bob winning?

- $(1/3)~$ of the time, Alice rolls above 20, and therefore wins.
- $(2/3) \times (1/20) = (1/30) ~$ of the time, Alice rolls below 21, and rolls the same as Bob.  Here, Bob wins.
- $~1 - (1/3) - (1/30) = (19/30)~$ of the time, Alice rolls below 21, and rolls differently than Bob.  By symmetry, Bob wins $~(1/2)~$ of the time here.

So, if Alice and Bob each roll once, then the probability of Bob winning is

$$\frac{1}{30} + \left[ ~\frac{19}{30} \times \frac{1}{2} ~\right] = \frac{21}{60}.$$

This implies that if Bob re-rolls (for any reason), his probability of winning automatically **becomes** $~\dfrac{21}{60}.~$

Now assume that Bob's first roll is $~b,~$ where $~b~$ is some element in $~\{1,2,\cdots,20\}.~$  If Bob does **not** re-roll, then his probability of winning is $~\dfrac{b}{30}.~$

Then, you have that $~\dfrac{10}{30} < \dfrac{21}{60} < \dfrac{11}{30}.~$

Therefore, to play optimally, Bob should re-roll if and only if his first roll is 10 or less.  This will occur $~(1/2)~$ of the time.

Further, when Bob does not re-roll, which will also be exactly $~(1/2)~$ of the time, it will be because his first roll was some element in $~\{11,12,\cdots,20\}.$
In this scenario (no re-roll), because his probability of winning, $~\dfrac{b}{30},~$ is **linear** to $~b,~$ you can assume that Bob rolled $~15.5~$ here.

Therefore, the overall probability of Bob winning is

$$\left[ ~\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{21}{60} ~\right] + \left[ ~\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{15.5}{30} ~\right] = \frac{13}{30}.$$

Comment: what do you mean by 10/30 < 21/60 < 11/30 ?

Comment: @XuShan If bob and alice each roll once, bob's probability of winning is (21/60).  So, if bob re-rolls, for any reason, his probability of winning automatically **becomes** (21/60).  Therefore, bob should re-roll if and only if his initial probability of winning is less than (21/60).  **Note** the two bullet-pointed assumptions made near the start of my answer.  Note also that 10/30 and 11/30 equal 20/60 and 22/60, respectively.  For what it's worth, this response is nothing more than a re-hash of my answer.  I suggest that you re-read my answer, in its entirety, more carefully.